# windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am wondering that if we write the following code on an event:

```
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

This will always navigate to Page1. Why, and how to override such behavior if I have to navigate on Page2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigate() method is an asynchronous method. It might be that your second call is executed while the first "navigation" is still in progress and therefore cancelled.
Try adding a small pause in between to check this.

EDIT:
You may cancel the first call to Navigate() either in the source page's [NavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) handler, the target page's [NavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) handler or in the [Navigating](http://www.wpseven.de/2010/08/wp7-redirecting-an-initial-navigation/) handler in the App class. Call `event.Cancel = true;` to cancel the navigation.

Comment: But I want the scenario (or code) that when second navigation request comes, cancel first one and start second navigation. Is there any way to achieve it?